# Can't boot anything newer than Ubuntu 10.04 (tried all currently supported releases): kernel panic

Tags: system-installation, 10.04, 10.10, 16.10

The last version of Ubuntu that works for me  ( in legacy mode) is 10.04 with 2.6.32 kernel. Starting with 10.10 and 2.6.35 it won't work. I'm also able to boot Trinity rescue kit with 2.6.37.1 kernel.
What are the differences between thee two releases that could prevent me from running it ?

Specs:

- cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U
- chipset: Intel Haswell-ULT rev. 09
- southbridge: H8x/P8x rev. C1
- ram: 4GB DDR3 - HMT351S6EFR8A-PB
- gpu: Intel integrated
- hdd: sshd Seagate ST1000LM014

here's the complete lshw output : http://pastebin.com/FtQBtUxF

While booting anything above 10.04 I get :
[image]

Comment: Did you also try all the currently supported versions, i.e. 12.04, 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10?

Comment: I've tried : 10.04, 10.10 , 11.04, 11.10, 12.10, 14.04.5, 16.04, 16.04.1, 16.10

Comment: Have you tried disabling your network card to see if that's the issue? After a quick search, the network card appears to be the cause in a lot of cases.

Comment: is it possible via kernel boot parameters ?